# Time Series Decomposition of weekly data

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

I am totally new to R and have just started using it. I have three years of weekly data. I want to decompose this time series data into trend, seasonal and other components. I have following doubts:

1. Which function I should use - `ts()`or `decompose()`
2. How to deal with leap year situation.

Please correct me if I am wrong, the frequency is 52.

Thanks in Advance. I would really appreciate any kind of help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Welcome to R!

Yes, the frequency is 52.

If the data is not already classed as time-series, you will need both `ts()` and `decompose()`.  To find the class of the dataset, use `class(data)`.  And if it returns `"ts"`, your data is already a time-series as far as R is concerned.  If it returns something else, like `"data.frame"`, then you will need to change it to time-series. Assign a variable to `ts(data)` and check the class again to make sure.

There is a monthly time-series dataset `sunspot.month` already loaded into R that you can practice on.  Here's an example.  You can also read the help file for `decompose` by writing `?decompose`

```
class(sunspot.month)
[1] "ts"

> decomp <- decompose(sunspot.month)

> summary(decomp)

         Length Class  Mode     
x        2988   ts     numeric  
seasonal 2988   ts     numeric  
trend    2988   ts     numeric  
random   2988   ts     numeric  
figure     12   -none- numeric  
type        1   -none- character

> names(decomp)
[1] "x"        "seasonal" "trend"    "random"   "figure"   "type"    

> plot(decomp)  # to see the plot of the decomposed time-series
```

The call to `names` indicates that you can also access the individual component data.  This can be done with the `$` operator.  For example, if you want to look at the seasonal component only, use `decomp$seasonal`.

[r](/questions/tagged/r) [time-series](/questions/tagged/time-series)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have one doubt,instead of decompose , can I use `stl()` to decompose weekly data into these components? Will both give me different results?

Comment: Per the `decompose` help file -- "The function `stl` provides a much more sophisticated decomposition."  Have a look at both of the help files.  Among other differences, `stl` uses Loess methods and `decompose` uses classic auto-regression and moving average models.  They will not produce the same results.