# Convert weekly data to time series 'ts' object

Tags: r, dataframe, time-series

I have the `weekly` data:

```
weekly <- structure(list(date = c("2013-01-07", "2013-01-10", "2013-01-21", 
"2018-01-23", "2018-02-00", "2013-02-11", "2013-02-13", "2013-02-25", 
"2013-03-00", "2013-03-11", "2013-03-13", "2013-03-25", "2018-00-01", 
"2018-00-08", "2018-00-15", "2018-00-22", "2018-00-29", "2018-05-06", 
"2018-05-13"), count = c(1750L, 1993L, 1816L, 1264L, 2042L, 1989L, 
2186L, 2118L, 2081L, 2110L, 2151L, 2069L, 1898L, 1862L, 1952L, 
1891L, 1758L, 1169L, 2009L)), row.names = c(NA, -19L), class = "data.frame")
```

I want to convert this data to the time series `ts` object so that I can forecast the data.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22188660/r-time-series-modeling-on-weekly-data-using-ts-object) but it didn't help me.

The code below creates `data.frame` with date and count

```
agr <-aggregate(input[1], input[2], FUN =  function(df) count=length(df))
colnames(agr)[2] <- "count"
```

The below the `weekly` data created:

```
weekly <- agr %>%
  tq_transmute(select     = count,
               mutate_fun = apply.weekly,
               FUN        = sum)
```

Now I want to convert this weekly data to time series data so that I can apply ARIMA model.

Comment: Didn't help you how?

Comment: Post the code you used please. Not an image of the dataset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the `weekly` data frame into time series object by using `ts` function with fractional frequency using `lubridate` package. Then you can use `HoltWinters` to predict next e.g. 3 weeks. Please see the code below:

```
weekly <- structure(list(date = c("2013-01-07", "2013-01-10", "2013-01-21", 
                                  "2018-01-23", "2018-02-00", "2013-02-11", "2013-02-13", "2013-02-25", 
                                  "2013-03-00", "2013-03-11", "2013-03-13", "2013-03-25", "2018-00-01", 
                                  "2018-00-08", "2018-00-15", "2018-00-22", "2018-00-29", "2018-05-06", 
                                  "2018-05-13"), 
                         count = c(1750L, 1993L, 1816L, 1264L, 2042L, 1989L, 
                                                           2186L, 2118L, 2081L, 2110L, 2151L, 2069L, 1898L, 1862L, 1952L, 
                                                           1891L, 1758L, 1169L, 2009L)), 
                    row.names = c(NA, -19L), 
                    class = "data.frame")

library(lubridate)
weekly_ts <- ts(weekly$count, 
   freq=365.25/7, 
   start= decimal_date(ymd(weekly[1, 1])))

#weekly_ts<- ts(weekly$count, frequency = 52)


m <- HoltWinters(weekly_ts, alpha = TRUE, beta = TRUE, gamma = FALSE)

library(forecast)
p <- predict(m, 3, prediction.interval = TRUE)
plot(m, p)
```

Output:
[image: graph]

Comment: The above answer has frequency=1, start=1 and end=19. I want a weekly analysis which starts from 12/2017 and ends with 7/2018(I posted the picture of the data but now it has been edited by @Artem). I have 32 weeks of data. I want to use ARIMA model and to forecast for the next 8 weeks. For weekly data I have to use frequency = 52. I am not able to decompose the data because of the less than 2 cycle of seasonal data. I skipped the decomposition and used auto.arima() function with the above data. This lead to a straight horizontal line of forecast which almost coincide with the regression line.

Comment: Edited w/frequency 52. You can try HoltWinters: `HoltWinters(weekly_ts, alpha = TRUE, beta = TRUE, gamma = FALSE)`. (But unfortunality there is no magic, to capture seasonality when you have less than a cycle is quite a challange ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Artem.